# Move element to X left when click button

Tags: jquery, css

When i'll click a button, the table it'll go to right and i'll be able to see more "Partners" tabs :). I just need the Javascript codes..:

HTML

```
<div class="proarena">
    <div class="proarena2">
        <div class="leftpro"></div>
        <div class="proPartners">
            <table class="Pro" cellspacing="0" style="left: 0px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#">Partners</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="darkside right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.proarena {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DiteoVd.png) 50% 100% no-repeat;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    width: 800px;
}

.proarena2 {
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgb(200,200,200) 0px 0px 5px;
    background: rgb(245,245,245);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: rgb(200,200,200) 0px 0px 5px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.proPartners {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 800px;
}

.Pro {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/LGTrDgE.png) 50% 0% repeat-y;
    border: 1px solid rgb(210, 210, 210);
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 968px;
}

.Pro tr, .Pro tr td {
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
}

.Pro tr:nth-child(1n):hover td:nth-child(1n) {
    background: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}

.Pro tr td:hover {
    outline: rgb(180, 180, 180) solid 1px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255)!important;
}

.Pro tr td {
    background: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 88px;
}

.Pro  tr:nth-child(2n):hover td:nth-child(2n) {
    background: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}
```

I don't think it's very easy, but it's not impossible. I tried some things but no result. :)

Comment: any attempt on your side?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a container where the width of the content inside is wider. If I understand your question properly, you want to have left/right buttons to essentially slide back and forth to reveal what's hidden.

Using jQuery's `.animate()` method, you can slide the table itself left and right. The example below is based strictly on your markup. Only difference being that I added the html elements for the left and right buttons, and I added `position: relative;` to the `.Pro` CSS class:

http://jsfiddle.net/lasha/8Zjza/

```
var $container = $(".proPartners");
var widthOfContainer = $container.width();
var $table = $(".Pro");
$(".right").on("click", function (e) {
    $table.animate({
        left: "-=" + widthOfContainer
    }, 300);
});
$(".leftpro").on("click", function (e) {
    $table.animate({
        left: "+=" + widthOfContainer
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It wasn't nice to see so many negative comments :).

Comment: @user2816226 you didn't have negative comments, you just get some downvotes because you didn't provide any attempt and relevant code. Now because, you made some effort which is nice, i'll upvote your question and btw this answer. Good continuation!

Comment: Thank you very much, and thank you Lasha and all members for help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't know where to start I will give you some idea on how to do this, however you will need to do research your self and attempt it. Come back again when you do some more work and ask question again with the sample.

Pseudo code:

in jQuery

Create an array of ALL of your elements you want to navigate: 
How to create array read here: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/

Once you have array set ALL elements to hidden if that is what you prefer to do:
jQuery hide: http://api.jquery.com/hide/
jQuery show: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Once you have that you can use .load and set one or more elements to visible, to start you off I would recommend doing 1 to see how it works.
So do something like `array[item1].show()`

Once you have that you will need to have navigation
Forward and Back
You can use .click method on each element / button
jQuery click: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Now you will need to do little coding in each:
for example when you go forward you can create variable position: like `i` and do following
`array elements` hide ALL or `array[i].hide()` then increment the `i` to next position `i++` and do `array[i].show()`.

Do the same for the back just use `i--`

There is many ways you can do this but this one should be straight forward and simple enough to get you going.

Comment: I still can't understand javascript and jQuery. Can you show me an example ? Thanks..!

Comment: I left you a links to all documentation you need to create this jQuery, even with a 0 previous knowledge of jQuery you will be able to accomplish this with few hours of reading and doing. Best of luck!